# Setting Protractor baseUrl dynamically

Tags: angularjs, protractor

In our end-to-end tests, we dynamically generate the URL endpoint for us to test against. In our Protractor configuration, I was hoping to use `beforeLaunch` or `onPrepare` to retrieve the URL endpoint and set it to `baseUrl` before running our tests. However it seems no matter what I try, Protractor runs tests with the wrong baseUrl, not the one I set in `beforeLaunch` or `onPrepare`.

We're using Protractor version 1.4.0. This is a simple configuration file demonstrating the issue:

```
exports.config =
    directConnect: true

    framework: 'jasmine'

    jasmineNodeOpts:
        isVerbose: true
        showColors: true
        includeStackTrace: true

    suites:
        login: 'login/**/*.coffee'
        full: '**/*.coffee'

    capabilities:
        browserName: 'chrome'

    beforeLaunch: ->
        setBaseUrl 'https://test-url.com'

    onPrepare: ->
        setBaseUrl 'https://test-url.com'

setBaseUrl = (baseUrl) ->
    exports.config.baseUrl = baseUrl
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

It looks like calling `browser.baseUrl = "https://test-url.com"` does the trick in `onPrepare`

Comment: How protractor sets baseurl , because when i am setting baselurl in onprepare function then also it is launching localhost